# Restoring in-app-purchase transactions, getting same transaction ID

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit, receipt-validation

I'm testing in app purchases in sandbox mode currently, and every time I restore previous transactions my receipt includes the original transcation ID in both the transaction_id fields and the original_transaction_id fields.

From reading the Apple documentation I understood that the restoring is a brand new transaction (meaning new transaction ID I assume).
And for that reason exactly the original_transaction_id is added to add information.

What I'm getting is equal original_transaction_id and transaction_id when restoring, is it because of being in sandbox? or am I understand everything wrong?

Comment: Have you found out why this happens?